# git rm -r removed "ignored" files. how can I get them back using git?

Tags: git, github, rm

Edit: I was able to recover my files from the trash, so I don't need a solution, but I'm interested in knowing how to recover using git (since it created the problem) and why any git operation would affect "ignored" files.

I have a .gitignore with entries like:

```
reference/
```

which is a folder where I had many large reference data files for my project.

I did a

```
git rm -r
```

and those files were deleted

I hadn't realized they were gone and, wanting to get everything back, used the github client to "Discard all changes..."

Now everything came back, except the files that were "ignored".

My operating system is OSX High Sierra.

How can I get them back?

Comment: Sounds like you ran into the part where git is very clever and beautiful, but not magic. When you delete a file that is not recorded by git (because you told it not to), it can't restore it through git. It's up to you to maintain your untracked files.

Comment: If i tell git to remove files, it should not remove the files I previously told it to ignore. It should ignore them. There's nothing clever or beautiful about asymmetric handling of destructive operations. That's the opposite of clever and beautiful.

Comment: [`git-rm - Remove files from the working tree and from the index`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm). You can add ignored files to a commit, and therefore `git rm` must be able to handle them. If you don't want files deleted, don't use anything that has `rm -r` in it.

Answer (score 1):

```
$git rm --help
```

> NAME
>          git-rm - Remove files from the working tree and from the index
>
> SYNOPSIS
>          git rm [-f | --force] [-n] [-r] [--cached] [--ignore-unmatch] [--quiet] [--] ...
>
> DESCRIPTION
>         Remove files from the index, or from the working tree and the index. **git rm will not remove a file from just your working directory.** (There is
>          no option to remove a file only from the working tree and yet keep it in the index; use /bin/rm if you want to do that.) The files being
>          removed have to be identical to the tip of the branch, and no updates to their contents can be staged in the index, though that default
>          behavior can be overridden with the -f option. When --cached is given, the staged content has to match either the tip of the branch or the file
>          on disk, allowing the file to be removed from just the index.

So when you deleted your files using `git rm` the files had been on the index or in the history already. Otherwise git would not have deleted them.

You cannot blame git to do what you told it.

---

to answer your question:

- If the files have bee in index (and not yet committet) you're lost. git cannot help.
- If your files where already committed you can check them out from the previous commit:

  ```
  git checkout HEAD^ path/to/deleted/file
  ```

  this will automatically add them to the index again so you have to delete them from *index only* using

  ```
  git rm --cached path/to/deleted/file
  ```